# Spring cloud gateway default routing doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I want enable default routing in my spring cloud gateway (no zuul) by service ids registered in eureka (application names) but I always got 404 error.

In my chat service's bootstrap.yml 
I have defined application name

```
spring:
  application:
    name: chat-service
```

and in application properties:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_HOST:localhost}:${EUREKA_PORT:8761}/eureka/
```

when I go to eureka's dashboard I can see registered my chat service and gateway as well.

Eureka's configuration in gateway application is same as chat service, but I also have this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
```

and next I also tried add explicit routes which din't work as well, but if I have discovery locator enabled set to `true` this shouldn't be needed right?

```
  routes:
    - id: chat-service-route
      uri: lb://chat-service
      predicates:
        - Path=**
```

I created test endpoint which I tried call directly on chat service and also with gateway. Direct call works fine so issue will be with routing.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        return "chat-service ready";
    }
}
```

What I did wrong? I am little desperate. I am using spring boot 2.2.2 and Hoxton.RELEASE cloud dependencies version

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means? What url did you try?

Comment: @spencergibb I'm sorry I should wrote it more cleaner. I always got 404 error for rest endpoint in chat service when I call it from gateway

Comment: What url are you calling on the gateway?

Comment: @spencergibb gateway runs on 8080 so I call localhost:8080/chat-service

Comment: And does chat service respond to /chat-service? Otherwise you need to rewrite the path

Comment: in logs is called eureka and looks like match with chat-service, also I tried call actuator on /chat-service/actuator and return some info about port where runs chat service

Comment: Not what I'm asking. Does http://<chatservicehost:port>/chat-service work?

Comment: I am little confused I dont have /chat-service endpoint in chat service. I tried it and no, I got 404 .. but when I try access directly without gateway isn't right behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing explicit routes and add below property to application yml. This works for me.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          lower-case-service-id: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end service:

```
server.port=8993
spring.application.name=department-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

In the api-gateway project:

```
server.port=9191
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route=INFO

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).